# Throw CustomException in place of ParseException in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to convert string to Date using two formats. But when the DateString does not match any of the two formats, it throws ParseException. I am catching this exception in my ServiceImpl and everything was fine. But now, I want to show some message to users regarding their incorrect format.
**Problem:** I am using catch block of ParseException to throw my customException and I know it is a bad practice. What can I do to avoid this.

ServiceImpl.java

```
try {
        CommonUtils.convertStringToDate(fooBean.getDateString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new DateParseException("Problems with your date.");
    }
```

GlobalExceptionHandler.java

```
@ExceptionHandler(DateParseException.class)
public String handleParseException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex, String msg){
    logger.error("DateParseException Occured :: "+ex.getMessage());
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("message", msg);
    return "error";
}
```

CommonUtils.java

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String dateString) throws ParseException{
        DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.USDATEFORMAT1);
        DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.USDATEFORMAT2);
        DateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.USDATEFORMAT3);
        DateFormat dateFormat4 = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.USDATEFORMAT4);
        boolean hyphenDelimeter = dateString.contains("-");
        boolean slashDelimeter = dateString.contains("/");
        int length = dateString.length();
        Date date = null;
        if(slashDelimeter){
            if(length == 10){
                    date = dateFormat1.parse(dateString);
            }else if(length == 8){
                    date = dateFormat2.parse(dateString);
            }
        }else if(hyphenDelimeter){
            if(length == 10){
                    date = dateFormat3.parse(dateString);
            }else if(length == 8){
                    date = dateFormat4.parse(dateString);
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: Is there no way to programmatically generate the format before you attempt to parse it? This would avoid the problem of having to throw a custom exception altogether.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer The data is coming from CSV file provided by user. Users have been told to use the format from the two formats defined in the application. But, I don't know if there is any way to generate the format.

Comment: If it's user-based input then your approach is safer. I would definitely keep an eye out for minimizing user input, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either adapt your exception to contain a "cause exception" one and wrap the caught exception inside your custom one, like so:

```
...
} catch (final ParseException e) {
  throw new DateParseException("Problems with your date.", e);
}
```

Or add a more relevant error message to the exeception you throw:

```
...
} catch (final ParseException e) {
  throw new DateParseException("Date could not be parsed.");
}
```

I would do the former to preserve the stack trace, so you can get a more detailed look into what went wrong.